# UIView Crash on 2nd call to create UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

I'm having a weird crash in a custom view. Its a simple debug panel with a button that creates a UIAlertView to grab a string. The XIB links the UIButton to the IBAction on clickInside, and UITextView is linked via the outlet to the mDebugText.

The view controller instantiates the view the first time everything works just fine. I can press the button and the Alertview pops up and I can type and dismiss it. No probpem.

However if my view controller removed/destroys the DebugView and later creates a new one when the button is pressed the app will crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've stripped out all the extraneous code and this is now down to the bare metal with no delegate on the UIAlertView and its still crashing the 2nd time the view is created and the button is pressed.

If I don't switch views I can press the button, kill the Alert and press again as many times as I like.

Any ideas on what might going wrong would be gratefully received.....

```
class DebugView : BaseView,UIAlertViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mDebugText: UITextView!

var mDelegate:DebugViewDelegate? = nil
var mMessage: String = ""

class func instanceFromNib(delegate:DebugViewDelegate? = nil) -> DebugView {
    let view = UINib(nibName: "DebugView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! DebugView
    view.refreshDisplay()
    view.mDelegate = delegate
    return view
}

override func refreshDisplay() {
    var debug:String = ""
    debug += "STATUS:" + mMessage + "\n\n"
    debug += "\n--END--"
    mDebugText.text = debug
}

@IBAction func onSelectEnterScan(sender: AnyObject) {
    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Fake Scans", message: "Enter Scan Detail", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
    alertView.show()
}
```

}

The crash occurs on the alertView.show() line. ViewController code is below, the viewTransition is used by a a lot of different views to slide/flip in various differing views and they all work just fine:

```
func onSelectDebug(animation:AnimationType) {
    if isUILocked() { return }
    setNavCurrent(Constants.NAVIGATOR_DEBUG)

    let newView:BaseView = DebugView .instanceFromNib(delegate: self)
    newView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mMainHolder.frame.size.width, height: mMainHolder.frame.size.height);
    viewTransition(newView, animation:animation)
}

func onSelectHome(animation:AnimationType) {
    if isUILocked() { return }
    setNavCurrent(Constants.NAVIGATOR_HOME)

    let newView:BaseView = HomeView.instanceFromNib(delegate: self)
    newView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mMainHolder.frame.size.width, height: mMainHolder.frame.size.height)
    viewTransition(newView, animation:animation)
}
```

The viewTransition function does a UIView.animateWithDuration to slide out the old view and in with the new view, new view is added, animation done and on completion the old view is removed from the superview and is no longer referenced. So if I cause an onSelectDebug the debug screen will slide in, I press the button, get the alert, the use the nav to cause onSelectHome, the home screen will slide in, the press the button to cause the call to onSelectDebug, the debug screen will slide in but I press the button on the new DebugView, bang, crash and death.

Crash detail: stack frame objc_msgSend in the main thread, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: where / how is your debug view being destroyed and recreated?

Comment: If I remove the line: alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput; then it will work fine, but I lose the input.

Comment: This does seem very strange indeed... A workaround may be to lazy load debug view as needed, then retain the view so you don't have to re-instantiate...

Comment: If I retain/recycle the DebugView it works fine, I'm beginning to suspect this might be a Swift/ARC bug!!